# Pdf conversion with ghostscript undesired border cut off

Tags: pdf, ghostscript

Hi,

I'm using ghostscript to convert pdf of various format to png images. My pdfs are in landscape format or normal.

I'm passing to gs this command (from c#):

```
string CmdArguments = string.Format("-o {0}%04d.png -sDEVICE=pngalpha -r600 -g2000x2000 -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 -c<</Orientation 3>> setpagedevice  {1}", outputfilename, inputfilename);
```

But I have always on every page had undesired cut off of right border.

How can I fix this issue?

Many thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are expecting the page to be scaled to fit the specified fixed page size, then you need to tell Ghostscript to do so, which you haven't done.

By the way <> setpagedevice isn't valid, it would also be a lot easier to understand if you would quote an actual complete string rather than the parameters to a C# method, those of us who don't grok C# might be able to understand it better. You've put a '-c' in there to treat the following as PostScript, but there's no -f to terminate PostScript processing before you reach the input filename. Frankly I'm surprised this does anything at all.

Try adding -dPDFFitPage.